# Removing IK constraints without leaving bones without motion

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

So I was just trying to make a mod for a game and I thought of using IKs for making it easier to make an animation.

[Simple animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2viu.gif)

And I would have to leave the bones by themselves without the IKs so that I could compile it into the game itself.

But as soon as I try to disable/remove the IKs the bones are left motionless.
I tried baking animations and it didn't help.

Comment: [`Object->Animation->Bake Action...`](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68154/935) - you need to enable visual keying to get the movement from constraints.